# Difference between "limit point" and "points in the closure"

Tags: general-topology

Given a topology $(X,T)$, $A\subset X$, $x \in X$ is a limit point of A if $\forall$ open $U$ that contains $x$, $(U\cap A)$\ {$x$} $\neq \emptyset$. $x \in X$ is in $cl(A)$ if $\forall$ open $U$ that contains $x$, $U\cap A$ $\neq \emptyset$. Is there any example that a point in the the closure of $A$ is not a limit point of A? Are the two equivalent in metric space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A point in a closed set is either a limit point or an isolated point (a point which has a neighbourhood which contains no other points of the set). For a reference, this is Theorem 17-E (page 97) of [*Introduction to Topology and Modern Analysis* by G. F. Simmons](http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=0e5Xq3fGnAgC).

Answer (score 2):

$X=\mathbb R$, $A=\{0,1\}$. Then $A$ is closed but none of its points is a limit point of $A$.

Comment: To be pedantic, that depends on the topology, so "assuming the usual topology".

Answer (score 1):

consider a finite set A of singletons in $\mathbb{R}$, there are no limit points, but they are al in $cl(A)$